# text classification with machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a data set, with news headlines and the category of that news. I wish I could predict the category of the news by entering only its headline.
I need to be able to classify text.
Thank you

Comment: i'm not very familiar with machine-learning in python, but i've used weka to analyse text, i used a method called string to vector which basically makes prediction based on the frequency of certain words, i've stemmed and tokenized the words.

Answer (score 0):

your question cannot be answered completely, but i can give you some starting points. 
, you need to do some own research
this tutorial will is good for start. [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/)

For local development i would suggest Anaconda for libraries etc and Jupyter notebooks.
Or
You can use google colab or Microsoft Azure notebook for it.

- Load required libraries,
- load data, check and clean your data
- Split dataset for train and test
- convert text to vectors
- train and test the model and make prediction

and some code for help,

```
# Split-out validation dataset
X = df_row['tweets'].values
Y = df_row['label'].values
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

vocab_size = 1000    
# define Tokenizer with Vocab Size
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
#X_test and X_train are data tweets(text columns)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='tfidf')
#X_train is now in vectorized form
```